# has_one relation automatically set nil if more than one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

Give a two models, with a `has_one` association:

```
class ShopInfo
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Shop
  has_one :shop_info
end


s = Shop.create
ss1 = s.create_shop_info
```

In some other place of my code I do

```
ss2 = s.create_shop_info
```

After this, ss1.shop_id is set to nil, so ss1 is now an orphan record.

**Is there any way to remove previous records instead of set them to nil?**

Comment: Why don't you update the previous shop_info record, instead of create a new one?

Comment: I am trying to prevent other developers to create orphan records doing this call. I could this for an isolate solution, but I won't prevent this behaviour for other developers in future code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the has_one association executes a `nullify`. Adding the `dependent: :destroy` solved the problem.

```
class Shop
  has_one :shop_info, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Just if someone wants more info, the ActiveRecord code for has_one replacement record is this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb#L24-L51

BUT if you add a `dependent` option in the association, executes the `delete` method as well:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb#L7-L22

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer! Did't known dependent option works this way.

Comment: because it's my own answer, I have to wait two days to accept it :(

Comment: @FranMartinez does this mean the default value for `:dependent` in `has_one` is `nullify` ?

Answer (score 1):

Fran, if you look at [the `has_one` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one), I think you want to use the `association=` method:

> **association=(associate)**
>
> Assigns the associate object, extracts the
>   primary key, sets it as the foreign key, and saves the associate
>   object. To avoid database inconsistencies, permanently deletes an
>   existing associated object when assigning a new one, even if the new
>   one isn't saved to database.

Which means your code might look like...

```
ss2.shop_info = ShopInfo.new(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found the solution reading again the documentation. Unfortunately your solution is not preventing other developers to have the same problem trying to do the create_shop_info call.